# How to read uncommitted transaction data in mongo

Tags: .net, mongodb

The mongo documentation [indicates that read uncommitted is the default isolation level](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#:%7E:text=Read%20uncommitted%20is%20the%20default,replica%20sets%20and%20sharded%20clusters.), but I can't seem to read uncommitted data from outside of the transaction with any read concern.

I am using dotnet, but feel free to give answers in other languages.

```cs
using var session = Client.StartSession();
session.StartTransaction();
Collection.InsertOne(session, myObject);
// outside of the transaction - in actual usage this would be another thread or process
var result = Collection
    .WithReadConcern(ReadConcern.Local)
    .Find(o => o.MyProperty = "test")
    .FirstOrDefault();
// this fails with any read concern
Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```